# Change git commit message for commits older than particular date

Tags: git

I need to update commit messages for commits, that were made before certain date. My idea for the code:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" < "2012-11-01T00:00:00" ];
        then
            cat && echo "#imported"
        else
            cat &
    fi' 
HEAD
```

Can the 'if' statement compare dates with greater than / less than at all?

Comment: Context: commit message update is needed, because older commits do not comply with server hooks.

Comment: The value of $GIT_AUTHOR_DATE contains spaces which you don't have in your string

Comment: Replacing T with spaces did not help, neither did using internal date/time format "if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" < "@1460964047 +0300" ];"

Answer (score 2):

The [`test` program](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)<sup>1</sup> usually *can* compare strings like this, but it does lexicographic comparisons.  The ability to do such comparisons [is an extension](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest), but is available on [Linux](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html), [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/test.1.html), and most if not all [BSDs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?test).

There are a number of issues with doing this:

- The `<` or `>` must be escaped from the shell.  `[ "abc" < "def" ]` runs `/bin/[` with arguments `"abc"` and `]`, with standard input being redirected from file `def`, assuming file `def` exists (otherwise you get an error).
- As already noted, the comparison is lexicographic.  This means that to compare dates, they must be in a form in which such a comparison produces the correct result.  Using ISO 8601 format will actually work, since the fields are fixed size and are in big-endian order.  However, `filter-branch` does not export the date in ISO 8601 form.  What you get instead looks like `1460884741 -0700`, for instance.  The first number is a time stamp in seconds since 1970, and the second is a time zone offset (which you should largely ignore and simply work directly in UTC).

Besides these problems, your message-filter needs to avoid backgrounding the `cat` command.  Hence, what you want is:

- First, convert 2012-11-01T00:00:00 into a UTC time stamp.  This is a bit tricky.  We can use python and its `time.mktime` but this insists on doing local time correction, so we must un-do the local time correction, which depends in part on whether DST is in force.  My local time zone offset is -08:00 except during DST (such as now) when it is -07:00.  This may thus be off by an hour (it was in my first paste, and I didn't even notice; edited now to fix):

  ```
  $ python -c 'import time; print(int(time.mktime((2012,11,1,-8,0,0,0,0,0))))'
  1351728000
  ```

  To verify that this is the correct time stamp:

  ```
  $ env TZ=UTC date -r 1351728000
  Thu Nov  1 00:00:00 UTC 2012
  ```
- Then, use this value in your `--msg-filter` with a numeric comparison on the first (non-offset) field in `$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` or `$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` as desired:

  ```
  ... --msg-filter 'cat; set $GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; \
    test $1 -lt 1351728000 && echo "#imported"' ...
  ```

All the other usual caveats about using `git filter-branch` apply, of course.

---

<sup>1</sup>`/bin/[` is a link to `/bin/test`.  When `test` is invoked as `[` it looks for a closing `]` but is otherwise the same program.  It is also built in to many shells for speed, but still implements the same semantics.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup>Or at least, is *supposed* to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ideas from torek, I updated my script:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" \< "@1351728000" ];
        then
                cat && echo "#imported"
        else
                cat &
        fi' HEAD
```

Notable changes:

- < is replaced with \<, which is equivalent to -lt
- Timestamp uses integer format and has a prefix "@"